Can I extrapolate number of deaths (n_event) from 5-year survival Kaplan Meier?
Let's say there are 52 patients in the negative margin group and 24 in the positive margin group. I'm presented with this statement on the survival rates: "Overall survival was similar in the positive margin group (5-year survival 70%, 95CI 44%−85%) compared with the negative margin group (5-year survival 61%, 95CI 45% −75%); p=.266"

Can I know how many people died (n_event) at the 5-year mark?
Because it says in the paper "There were 29 (38%) patients that died during the study period. Of the patients that died, 16 patients died
prior to 5-year follow-up."
And if I use the given percentages, I have the number 28.
Am I understanding what these percentages mean?

When people report a percentage of people with an event by a certain time, it is often unclear whether they are talking about the raw percentage of people (that ignores losses to follow-up and just calculated patients with event / total patients * 100%) or whether they are talking about the Kaplan-Meier estimate (that accounts for losses to follow-up). The number that is given sounds more like a raw percentage, because $29/(52+24) * 100\% \approx 38.158 \%$ (while 28 patients would be about 36.842%).
Every step in the step function is one or more event/death. You can try to reconstruct the individual patient data e.g. using the methods proposed in R packages such as IPDfromKM (and perhaps using digitize). That would essentially re-construct the individual patient data of the two groups and you'd (up to the precision with which you marked axes and clicked on the plots) know the time each patient had their event (on censoring times you have less information).
Unless you find information where it's more clear what the authors are giving you, that's the most reliable way to know that I can think of, if you don't want to contact the authors. Contacting the authors and asking for more information has the potential to give you a clear answer (but I cannot predict whether the authors would answer - from personal experience, I have a 0% success rate with requesting things that were stated to be "available upon request").

I unfortunately have the same experience with data as well... I was referring to the fact stated 16 patients died within 5 years, while from the Kaplan-Meier percentages, I get the number 28 patients that died within 5 years.
